# Cisco Spark: Is there a way to do @all mentions with the bot API?

Tags: rest

[The documentation for message formatting has examples for mentioning individuals by email or ID.](https://developer.webex.com/formatting-messages.html) Is it possible to do the @all mention that alerts everyone in the channel via the API? It is possible to do so in the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Right now there is no way to do @all mentions via the API. It is a client-only feature.